# Don't scroll and display all PictureBoxes in Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am getting images from a database and passing them as a List to a Form, where I am creating a Panel. I also create a PictureBox, and add them to the panel - according to the number of pictures from the list (in my case, I load 120 pictures from the database with a size of 800 x 600). In a normal form of window size, which is according to FormWindowState.Normal, I have only 54 images in the Panel, but if I expand the window with a mouse click, which corresponds to FormWindowState.Maximized, the scrollbar continues and all the images are displayed.
After this manipulation, I return to the normal state of the window which is according to FormWindowState.Normal, now all the pictures are visible and I can scroll them.

Also, if I set the size of all pictures to 200x200, then I also can see them all at once, but the matter is, that I need to display pictures exactly 800 x 600 in size.

How to make displaying the entire collection at once in the normal window state with abillyty of scrolling.

```
public partial class ShowReferences
    {
        private List<Image> imagesCollection;
        private Panel panelToShow;

        public ShowReferences(List<Image> images)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imagesCollection = images;
            panelToShow = new Panel();
            panelToShow.AutoScroll = true;
            panelToShow.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Controls.Add(panelToShow);

            for (int i = 0; i < this.imagesCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
                pictureBox.Image = this.imagesCollection[i];
                pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
                pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, i * pictureBox.Height);
                this.panelToShow.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

I also wrote down the values of the scroll elements, when the window is resized, as I understand it, the error is most likely in their values, but for some reason I cannot set them manually

Action: When fill panel with elements Window state :Normal=======================23.02.2023 16:31:31

```
panelToShow.AutoScrollMargin :{Width=0, Height=0}
panelToShow.AutoScrollMinSize :{Width=0, Height=0}
panelToShow.AutoScrollOffset :{X=0,Y=0}
panelToShow.AutoScrollPosition :{X=0,Y=0}
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.Value :0
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.Maximum :100
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.Minimum :0
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange :10
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange :1
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.Value :0
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.Maximum :100
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.Minimum :0
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.LargeChange :10
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.SmallChange :1
Action: Change window state size. Window state :Maximized=======================23.02.2023 16:31:34

panelToShow.AutoScrollMargin :{Width=0, Height=0}
panelToShow.AutoScrollMinSize :{Width=0, Height=0}
panelToShow.AutoScrollOffset :{X=0,Y=0}
panelToShow.AutoScrollPosition :{X=0,Y=-32591}
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.Value :0
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.Maximum :799
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.Minimum :0
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange :583
panelToShow.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange :5
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.Value :32591
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.Maximum :66384
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.Minimum :0
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.LargeChange :793
panelToShow.VerticalScroll.SmallChange :5
Action: Change window state size. Window state :Normal=======================23.02.2023 16:31:36
```

Tried to redraw both the form and the element itself and set values for the scroll elements manually

Comment: It is a histerical limitation of the [WM_VSCROLL message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll), the scrollbar position is delivered as a HIWORD.  A 16-bit signed value, the maximum is 32767 (aka short.MaxValue).  32767 / 600 = 54.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel) instead. Set the `FlowDirection` as desired (`TopDown`) and add controls to it. The controls are positioned automatically (the `Location` property is ignored). Set `AutoScroll` to `true` to get scroll bars. Set `WrapContents` to `false` to make it behave like a `ListBox`.

You can set the `Margin` property of the added controls to adjust their spacing.

A cool trick is to use a `CheckBox` with the `Appearance` property set to `Button` instead of a `PicturBox`. This lets you select the images. You can assign the image to the `BackgroundImage` property and select an appropriate `BackGroundImageLayout` value (e.g., `Zoom`).

Alternatively, you can also set the `Image` property, but it has no Layout property so that the image will always be displayed un-zoomed and un-streched. But it has the advantage that you can use the `TextImageRelation` property to, for instance, add a text below the image.

If you make the box a little bit larger than the image, you will better see the `CheckedBackColor`. You can set that one when using the `Flat` appearance.